# How to Generate a Http Post request and print the request before sending it using Java

Tags: java, xml, apache, http

I need to generate HTTP POST request using java the request format is below

```
  <request version="3.9" principal="c1Prov" credentials="c1Prov">
     <target name="UserAPI" operation="createUser">
      <parameter>
       <user>
       <name><SUBSCRIBER_ID></name>
       <login-name><SUBSCRIBER_LOGIN_ID></login-name>
          <password>
        <value><SUBSCRIBER_PASSWORD></value>
        </password>
          <organization>
       <qualified-name>/BTCL_FIXED/<WHOLESALE_ORG_NAME></qualified-name>
       </organization>
       <account><name><SUBSCRIBER_ACCOUNT></name></account>
       <profile-set>
       <qualified-name>/BTCL_FIXED/<FIXED_PROFILE_SET_NAME></qualified-name>
        </profile-set>
            </user>
        </parameter>
         </target>
         </request>
```

I tried the below piece of code but it doesnt print anything. 
1. Am i doing it the correct way?
2. why is it not printing anything?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.baidu.com");
     String xml = "<target name=\"DomainAPI\" operation=\"createDomain\"><parameter><domain><name><DOMAIN_NAME></name><owning-organization><qualified-name>/BTCL_FIXED</qualified-name></owning-organization><profile-set><qualified-name>/BTCL_FIXED/Wholesale Fixed Dom PS</qualified-name><type>domain</type></profile-set></domain></parameter></target>";
     HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     post.setEntity(entity);
     System.out.println(post.Entity());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`entity = post.getEntity().getContent()` - and you'll get an InputStream for an entity.
Get a string from it:

```
String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Use a StringEntity instead of ByteArrayEntity:

```
new StringEntity(xml, Charset.defaultCharset())
```

Comment: Thanks Michel_T, it helped.  My other question in the xml part which i pasted above, does everything should be part of  request entity? This is the first time i am working on xml over htttp stuff so not clear which part of the xml should go in header and which should go into ENtity.

Comment: Yes, you're right - your xml data should be in a body of the request (in Entity).